# Image element not occupying the full rectangle in SVG - jquery

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-svg

Please refer the below SVG.

```
<svg width="5cm" height="4cm" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<rect x="0" y="0" width="150px" height="150px"/>

    <image xlink:href="firefox.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="150px" width="150px"/>
</svg>
```

The output looks like below.

[image]

**How can i make the image to occupy the full rectangle ?**

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: Are you sure, your "full rectangle" is the rect element? Perhaps the image just doesn't occupy the dimensions specified in your svg-tag (5cm x 4cm).

Comment: i want to make image fully occupy the rectangle space. i have checked your js fiddle it seems to be same problem in left side corner and right side corner. if the image is fully occupied in rectangle means the interior color of rectangle will not be visible for us. but now its visible slightly in left side as well as right side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for images having the same aspect ratio as your rect: http://jsfiddle.net/M24gX/

```
<svg width="8cm" height="8cm" version="1.1">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="150px" height="150px" fill="red"/>
    <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/"
        x="0" y="0" height="150px" width="150px"/>
</svg>
```

Doesn't work for images having a different aspect ratio as your rect: http://jsfiddle.net/5v9bd/

```
<svg width="8cm" height="8cm" version="1.1">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="150px" height="150px" fill="red"/>
    <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/300/150/sports/"
        x="0" y="0" height="150px" width="150px"/>
</svg>
```

If you want the image to fill the full 150x150px of the rectangle regardless of its aspect ratio, you:

- assign height="150px" and width="150px" (like you already did)
- **assign preserveAspectRatio="none"** to allow the image to have a non-uniform scaling

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Fq96J/

```
<svg width="8cm" height="8cm" version="1.1">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="150px" height="150px" fill="red"/>
    <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/300/150/sports/"
        x="0" y="0" height="150px" width="150px" preserveAspectRatio="none"/>
</svg>
```

preserveAspectRatio is an attribute you should definitely know inside out when working with SVG so i recommend to read some docs and play around with it a bit. Good explanation can be found at

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on [my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XbzRX/). Can you reproduce it on a JSFiddle?

```
<svg width="8cm" height="8cm" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<rect x="0" y="0" width="150px" height="150px" stroke="red" stroke-width="3"/>

    <image xlink:href="firefox.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="150px" width="150px"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: i want to make image fully occupy the rectangle space. i have checked your js fiddle it seems to be same problem in left side corner  and right side corner. if the image is fully occupied in rectangle means the interior color of rectangle will not be visible for us. but now its visible slightly in left side as well as right side.